# How do i set height of a GWT Grid?

Tags: javascript, gwt, listbox, grid

We are using GWT 2.4.0. We are using Grid in our application. But we are not able to set height of a grid.For reference,please have a look into the following image:
[image]

In the above image,you can find the listbox with grid in the left side having a lot options.But we need to display only 10 items with scroll bar.Is there any way to achieve this?Throw me in right direction.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with some css rules?

Example:

```
#myid {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 450px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

if you are working with ListBox (http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html)

```
lb.setVisibleItemCount(10);
```

Comment: can you have mistaken the priority css order?: http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/

Comment: no i tried to edit in firebug also every thing is effecting like width,background .. etc but height is not

Comment: overflow: auto and height works together when making a scrollable area, try also with !important rule

Comment: @Rare Piece:Ideally lb.setVisibleItemCount(10) have to work. Have you tried it by updating GWT code? As in above comments you mentioned you tried with firebug.

Comment: @jaxb : no am not using ListBox. I am usinf DualListbox with drag and drop.For reference,please check this url : http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#DualListExample

Answer (score 0):

```
 listBox.setVisibleItemCount(10);
```